# How do you correctly store an httponly cookie containing a refresh token in the client?

Tags: reactjs, api, doorkeeper, httponly, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have been reading up on the topic of securing an API using doorkeeper. For the most part it has been pretty straight forward to set up the access token, refresh token pair. The issue I am currently having is what to do with the refresh token. The approach that appears to be most popular (from the posts that I have read on the topic) is to store the refresh token in an httponly cookie and place it in local storage. I understand setting the httponly cookie on the server side prior to making a request, I do not understand how to store that cookie in local storage. I must be misunderstanding something, because for starters it seem counter intuitive to use JavaScript to store a piece of data that has no JavaScript API to manipulate it. So could someone please explain to me how to go about this?

Comment: Yeah, your instinct is correct. You can't access a httponly cookie with JavaScript and put it in local storage. If it's in a cookie already, what's the reason to also put it in local storage?

Comment: As you noted, the JavaScript API cannot manipulate it, which is exactly what you want for security reasons. Don't store refresh tokens in local storage. HttpOnly (and secure) cookies are the way to go.

Comment: @Nick I might not completely understand how cookies function. The goal it to prevent users from having to sign in every 5 minutes or so when their access token expires. It was my understanding that in order to accomplish this you need to persist the refresh token somewhere in the client so that when the access token expires, the client can send it back to the authorization server to get a new access token refresh token pair. It is my current understanding that once a cook is set it is sent with every request to and from the client, but I don't really understand the life span of that occurrence

Comment: 5 minutes is an extremely short expiration window, typically expiration times are more in the range a few hours, days, weeks, or 1-3 months; I think it's worth evaluating how taxing the increase in requests could be for your auth server (+ billing costs) and how enticing of an attack surface your API really is (e.g., how much damage can a bad actor with a stolen token do? You might find the bigger risk is leaky logic within your API). You might benefit from some of the stuff in the OAuth blog: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: @Allison those are all important considerations. I have tried to build the API in such a way that its very contextually sterile to an outside observer, key functionality intentional obscure by getting "creative" with antipatterns, and data mutation is very tightly coupled to the intended actor. One thing you pointed out that I may have not completely fleshed out is the impact on servers and cost such a short token life span could have, I might need to graph that out.